# How to play .mov files using Ubuntu "Videos"?

Tags: video, apple, totem

How can I play .mov files on an iPhone using the Ubuntu built-in "Videos?"

Using Ubuntu 14.04 with built-in Videos 3.10.1 based on Totem.  Ubuntu restricted extras is installed.  When I try to play the .mov file I get the error message "An error occurred Stream contains no data."  There is no video, no sound.

I don't want to install another video player just to handle .mov files, I would like to play them with the built-in Videos program, how do I do this?

Comment: It totem player bug see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/379793

Answer (score 2):

Just discovered that the built-in Totem based Videos player will in fact play .mov files, just not from the iPhone device.  The .mov files play when copied to the Ubuntu machine or NAS drive.