# How to play iPhone *.MOV files?

Tags: video, iphone, 23.04

How to play iPhone *.MOV files in Ubuntu 23.04?

This similar question is very old and doesn't have an answer: [How to play .mov files using Ubuntu "Videos"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541359/how-to-play-mov-files-using-ubuntu-videos)

I have `gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64 1.22.2-1` installed, and I am using "Videos" (i.e. Totem) version 43.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 installed as `deb` package.

Comment: If you have a old computer that does not have a H265 decoder, then it may not be able to play videos taken with iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install all the necessary codecs with

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Install VLC with

```
sudo apt install vlc
```

Finally, run the video with vlc media player.

---

In case there are still any errors, run the command `vlc /path/to/video.MOV` and post the terminal output.

Comment: I don't even need to install ubuntu-restricted-extras, with vlc it works out of the box for me.

Comment: Per @mook765's comment, installing VLC was sufficient. I did not need to install `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. However, that may be because I already had the packages that are typically included with `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, such as `libavcodec-extra`, `gstreamer1.0-libav`, `gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly`, and `gstreamer1.0-vaapi`.

Comment: @Enterprise On my system only `gstreamer1.0-libav` is installed (a dependency of libreoffice), not the others. `gstreamer1.0-libav` is also a dependecy of `totem`, so if this package is the one which would be needed to play `.MOV`-files, why totem isn't able to. `vlc`  plays most codecs with no codec packs needed as stated [here](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/)

Comment: Based on this information, perhaps all that is needed are the two packages, `vlc` and `gstreamer1.0-libav`.